# ImportError: cannot import name CredentialsNDBProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

using appengine and Ferris, I am receiving this error when trying to use bulkloader.yaml.

```
from oauth2client.appengine import CredentialsNDBProperty, StorageByKeyName
```

ImportError: cannot import name CredentialsNDBProperty

Answer (score 0):

Have you this problem only when your code is deployed ?

In localhost, if you have oauth2client installed into python/site-package, AppEngine devserver use it. But when you deploy your application on App Engine, you need to embed this library in your project.

The list of third-party libraries include into App Engine python runtime : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: Thanks So much for your response... it's happening both on local dev server and remote. I'm using ferris as the mvc framework which includes oauth2 as part of it's core package. I am new to python, so I'm sure i'm missing something. It seems like the oauth library is not being properly included in my bulkloader.yaml file